# PHP - Explode or Implode Values into an Array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm creating a simple survey and I want the values in the column to be just (1) one row and separated with "|". But the only problem is, how do I save those values that I've got from the $_POST into an array on my database? For example:
Male|Employed|Married| instead of this...

[image: Click here for the screenshot]

```
<?php
    $cnt = 1; // VARIABLE FOR QUESTIONS //
    $query = "SELECT * FROM questions";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
        $choices = explode ("|", $row->choices);
        if(isset($_POST['submit_post']))
        {              // eq - radio button name (choices) for $cnt - question # //
            $choice = $_POST["eq$cnt"];  // What to do in this $_POST part? //
            $query = "INSERT INTO users(answers)";
            $query .= "VALUES ('{$choice}')";
            $create_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        }            
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <?php 
        if($row->num ==0)
        {  
            $num="&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
        } else 
        {
            $num=$row->num.".&nbsp; ";
        }   
    ?> 
    <p id="eqIdentify_<?php echo $cnt ?>"><strong><?php echo $num; echo $row->questions; ?></strong> <?php  ?> <?php echo $cnt; ?>
    <?php               
        // VARIABLE FOR CHOICES //
        for($a=0;$a<count($choices);$a++) 
        { 
    ?>
    <br/><label><input type="radio" name="eq<?php echo $cnt;?>" value="<?php echo $choices[$a] ?>" /><?php echo $choices[$a]?></label>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
<?php 
        $cnt = $cnt + 1;
    } 
?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_post">
</form>
```

Comment: vardump $choice after it has been assigned to the posted data;
What's the result?

Answer (score 0):

change your table structure so you have a field for each of the questions.

like 
`ID Question1 Question2`

and then change your insert query such

```
INSERT INTO `answers`( `question1`, `question2`, `question3`, `question4`) VALUES ([value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5])
```

But please please look in to PDO and prepared query's

Comment: Yeah, I will. Already researched about PDO and prepared statement. Just kinda learning php step by step. Thanks for the response, but I think I shouldn't change my table structure since I provided a table for the survey questions, with the column for questions and its choices which are separated with "|" and only displayed through the explode function that I used here: *$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
                $choices = explode ("|", $row->choices);*